# How To Support Devices With Different Capabilities Gracefully

Tags: android, ionic2, chromebook

I have written an app whose AndroidManifest.xml has this section in it:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" android:targetSdkVersion="25" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
```

I have a hunch that these lines are resulting in my application being determined to be "unsupported" for a number of devices, with the most interest class to me being Chromebooks. These permissions are not strictly necessary for the app to function, and in fact they are being implied by Cordova plugins. The only one the app *really* relies on currently is ACCESS_WIFI_STATE.

So how can I ease the restrictions being perceived by the Play Console? Do I actually have to branch my app into two apps, one of which really does not need those "nice to have" permissions in order for Chromebooks to be supported? Or is there some other way?